# Object doesn't support property or method 'reverse'

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '');
  var copy = str.replace(/\W+/, '');
      console.log(copy.reverse);
 
  if (copy.reverse() == str) {
    console.log("true");
    return true;
  } else {
  console.log("false");
    return false;
  }
}

palindrome("Hel lo");
```

I am checking for palindromes it is one of freecodecamps algorithms and I am getting the error that "Object doesn't support property or method 'reverse'". Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Short version: `function palindrome(str) { var clean = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, ''); return clean === clean.split('').reverse().join(''); }`.

Comment: MDN has a [list of String methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) - note that `.reverse()` isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.reverse can be used to reverse the contents of an array in place with mutation, but not string. to make it work, see sample below which split string into array and reverse and join it back.

```
function palindrome(str) {
 str = str.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '');
 var copy = str.replace(/\W+/, '');
  if (copy.split("").reverse().join("")==str){
   return true;
}
   else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: You can also get rid of the `if-else` statements and just `return copy.split("").reverse().join("") === str;` instead. And remove the second `reverse` as it still causing the same problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: You don't even need the `copy`. `function palindrome(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\W+/, '');  
  return str.split('').reverse().join('') === str;
}`

Comment: my bad, is extra typo.

Answer (score 0):

`.reverse()` will work just for **Array** and not for `string`.

Hence you will need to `.split` it first in order to `reverse` it.

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '');
  var copy = str.replace(/\W+/, '').split('');

  if (copy.reverse().join('') == str) {
    console.log("true");
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log("false");
    return false;
  }
}

palindrome("hel eh");
```